# Getting values from data (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my code I have these lines inside of a ngOnInit:

```
this.state.params.subscribe(
      (params: any) => {
        console.log("Estes sao os parametros: " + params['id']);
        if(params['id']){
          console.log("ID confirmado");
          this.data = this.cteDadosService.getCte(params['id']);
          this.data.subscribe(
              cte => {
                this.cte = cte.data[0].CTe[0] || [];
                this.idEmitente = cte.data[0].CTe[0].idEmitente; 
                console.log("CT-e:");
                console.log(this.cte);//show the content of this.cte correctly              
              },
            )
            this.data.subscribe(
              nf => {
                this.nf = nf.data[2].nf || [];
                console.log("NF:");
                console.log(this.nf);//show the content of this.nf correctly
              },
            this.data.subscribe(
              carga =>{
                this.carga = carga.data[1].carga || [];
                console.log("Carga:")
                console.log(this.carga);//show the content of this.carga correctly
              }
            )
            )

          }
        }
      )
```

Where this.cte, this.nf and this.carga are private and any = [].

Well the problem is: outside of the function "this.state.params.subscribe" these privates have no values. For example:

```
somefunction()
{
 console.log(this.cte);// show [] on console
 console.log(this.nf);// show [] on console
 console.log(this.carga);// show [] on console
}
```

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: When do you call `somefunction`? The problem may be that you call it before the callback of `this.state.params.subscribe` has completed. Put a button in your view and set `(click)="somefunction()"` on it. You may see the correct values in the console when you click the button.

Comment: This.state.params.subscribe is the first thing that ngOnInit do. Somefunction is always before. Outside ngOnInit it works perfectly. This isn't solve my problem but you give me a light at all. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call this.someFunction() from inside the subscribe function becuase those are aynchronous and gets the value asynchronously.

Comment: And another question: I need the data values to insert into a FormGroup inside of the ngOnInit. How can i do that?

Comment: @RafaelTasaka Write the form group initialisations in a separate function and Call that too inside the subscribe function.